# Pull Record Types per Permission Set through Metadata API

Tags: apex, soql, metadata-api, record-type, permission-sets

I'm trying to list the Record Types per Permission Set. Unfortunately, this cannot be done through SOQL Query (IIRC).

That said, can somebody help me on how to achieve this through Metadata API (or others)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to be retrieved through Metadata API. To use this code you need to have MetadataService class from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls

For this example you should include `YOUR_PERMISSION_SET_API_NAME_HERE` in placeholder the list to be retrieved. You can also request up to 10 permission sets in one callout.

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm#PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility_title).

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> permissionSets = (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet', new List<String>{'YOUR_PERMISSION_SET_API_NAME_HERE'}).getRecords();

for (MetadataService.PermissionSet permissionSet_i : permissionSets) {
    for (MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility recordType_i : permissionSet_i.recordTypeVisibilities) {
        System.debug(recordType_i.recordType + ' is visible: ' + recordType_i.visible);
    }
}
```